# Adding Electronic Seal through api gives error

Tags: docusignapi

I have added seal recipients in envelope. I have got electronic seals enabled on the account. I have added only a seal recipient and the Demo Seal guid in the recipientSignatureProvider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
         <emailSubject>Email Subject.</emailSubject>
         <status>sent</status>
         <documents>
               <document>
                     <name>1</name>
                     <documentId>1</documentId>
               </document>
         </documents>
         <recipients>
               <seals>
                     <sealSign>
                           <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                           <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
                           <recipientSignatureProviders>
                                 <recipientSignatureProvider>
                                       <sealName>a6176xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</sealName>
                                 </recipientSignatureProvider>
                           </recipientSignatureProviders>
                     </sealSign>
               </seals>
         </recipients>
   </envelopeDefinition>
```

I get following error in the envelope audit.

Protect and Sign Demo (Client ID: dde5xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) replied: Error - ILLEGAL_DATA - Http error connecting to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/vdev/signature/signhashsessioninfo Code 400 {"errorCode":"UNSPECIFIED_ERROR","message":"An Error Occurred."}

What am I doing wrong ?
The envelope status stays as "sent". 
My expectation is it should be "complete" and seal applied in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The vdev path is limited to DocuSign applications. You should be using .../v2.1

Also, you need the seal functionality to be enabled for your demo sandbox account. Contact go-live@docusign.com (include your account id) to have this done.

Comment: Got the same error when I used V2.1, This is a sandbox account, which I need for development purpose only. I have the seal functionality enabled on the sandbox account. I have received a demo seal. a6176xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.

I get the same error even when I create the envelopes from DocuSign UI, dragging the seal image in the document and then sending it.

Comment: If you get the same error using the DocuSign web tool, then that is what needs to be solved first. Check the seals documentation in the DocuSign administration and user guides. If no success, contact DocuSign support. After it works via the user tool, move to the API.

Comment: I am following up with Docusign Support on this,